# Changing primary key / index breaks group by in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two branches where I am using the exactly same PostgreSQL query but the group by clause becomes invalid for some reason.

I have changed the primary key from `id` to composite `(tenant_id, id)`.

**The old documents table**

```
Documents
                                                  Table "public.documents"
             Column             |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                Default                
--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------
 id                             | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('documents_id_seq'::regclass)
 user_id                        | integer                     |           |          | 

Indexes:
    "documents_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_documents_on_user_id" btree (user_id)
```

**The new documents table**

```
Documents
             Column             |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                Default                
--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------
 id                             | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('documents_id_seq'::regclass)
 user_id                        | integer                     |           |          | 
 tenant_id                      | bigint                      |           | not null | 

Indexes:
    "documents_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (tenant_id, id)
    "index_documents_on_user_id" btree (user_id)
    "index_documents_on_tenant_id_and_id" UNIQUE, btree (tenant_id, id)

Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_5ca55da786" FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id) REFERENCES tenants(id)
```

Now, for some reason, my SQL query is no longer valid on the **new** branch - I have no idea why? How does the grouping work? Why can I no longer use this query as it was before?

Here is my SQL

```
SELECT
  "documents".*
FROM
  "documents"
GROUP BY
  "documents"."id"
```

(the error I am getting on the **new branch**)

```
ERROR: column "documents.user_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: so what is unclear about it, you need to specify what user_id, tennent_id you want, So add MAX/Useir:id), MAX(tennet_id), and see what ypu get else use other aggregation function till you get your wanted result

Comment: The issue is unrelated to the primary key. All columns not present in the `GROUP BY` clause should appear **aggregated** in the select list. That is, you need to use `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`, etc, for every column, except for the column `id`. Change that `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, *all* columns that appear in the `SELECT` list outside of aggregate functions must be in the `GROUP BY` clause. But if the primary key is in `GROUP BY`, all the other columns of that table are implied and don't need to be listed. So as soon as the column was no longer the primary key, you had to list the other one too.

This was introduced in PostgreSQL commit [e49ae8d3bc588294d07ce1a1272b31718cfca5ef](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=e49ae8d3bc588294d07ce1a1272b31718cfca5ef), see the discussion [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20100807024409.35E3A7541D7@cvs.postgresql.org).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The SQL is actually generated by Ruby on Rails so that's why it surprised me that it used to work before and now it doesn't.

Comment: When that feature was implemented in Postgres, I thought it was, because it is defined by the SQL standard.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I looked and could not find anything in the standard. So I have removed that claim. But I linked the discussion, and it does not seem to reference the standard either way.

Comment: [This thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/18819.1283700945%40sss.pgh.pa.us) and [this thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/18104.1539196218%40sss.pgh.pa.us#d77b3c9b2bf1747e3354239611c88a2c) got me to assume that the detection of functional dependencies for GROUP BY are part of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Comments are incorrect, the solution is to do this.

```
SELECT
  "documents".*
FROM
  "documents"
GROUP BY
  "documents"."id", "documents"."tenant_id"
```

There is no reason to group by `user_id`, for some reason, all the columns from the composite key need to be present in the group by clause.